# React Native rowID giving error undefined is not an object

Tags: listview, react-native

I am trying to make a listview full of buttons, and if you click a button it sends information that was on that button to the next page.  I have managed to get the listview correct as well as the buttons are able to navigate to the next page, but I cant manage to work out how to use rowID to work out which button was pressed.  I have the following code but for some reason rowID is giving an error undefined is not an object when it is clicked, when I change rowID with a number (say 1) it works perfectly,  any ideas?

Thanks so much

```
    var woolworths = {
  'title': "Woolworths",
  "description":'"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."',
  'img': require('../assets/woolworths.jpg')
};

var checkers = {
  'title': "Checkers",
  "description":'"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."',
  'img': require('../assets/checkers.jpeg')
};

var picknpay = {
  'title': "Pick 'n Pay",
  "description":'"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit    anim id est laborum."',
  'img': require('../assets/picknpay.jpg')
};

var partners = [woolworths, checkers, picknpay];

class Partners extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
     this.gotoPartner = this.gotoPartner.bind(this);
    this.ds= new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !==     r2})
    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this._partners()),
    }
  }
  gotoPartner(rowID:number){
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: partners[rowID].title,
        component: Partner,
         passProps: {partner:partners[0]},
         backButtonTitle: 'Back',
      });
  };

    _partners(){
      var dataBlob = []
      for (var ii = 0; ii < partners.length; ii++) {
        dataBlob.push(partners[ii].title);
      }
      return dataBlob;
    }


_renderRow(rowData, rowID){
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableHighlight
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => this.gotoPartner(rowID)}
                  underlayColor='transparent'>
                    <View style={styles.textimgholder}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>{rowData}</Text> 
                        <View style={styles.imgHolder}>
                            <Image source=            {require('../assets/arrowIcon.png')} 
                              style={styles.arrowIcon}/>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <Separator />
    </View>
    )
}
  render () {
    return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <FullSep />
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
      />
        </ScrollView>

      )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

renderRow takes four arguments: rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={() => this.gotoPartner(rowID)}
  underlayColor='transparent'>
          <View style={styles.textimgholder}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>{rowData}</Text> 
           </View>
       </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>
   )
}
```

If you need to get the rowID, you need to first pass in the sectionID, then the rowID.

I've set up a working version, alerting the partners[rowID] on click: https://rnplay.org/apps/OyyXlw

Comment: Thank you so much, cant believe this was the problem i have spent so long trying to figure out.  

Sorry for editing question and answering other answers, never saw this answer until now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `title: partners[rowID].title` and perhaps it should be `title: this._partners[rowID].title`. Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: Why do you think the underscore needs to be added?

Comment: Sorry, I think perhaps you didn't post all of your code in your example. I don't see where `partners` without the underscore is defined. I guess I was going on the assumption that this was a complete example.

Comment: partners is just an object i thought it would be intuitive what it was and I didnt want to put in too much code I will add it in now though.